# Remove Previouse Instances in a Pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large output file (~25000 lines) of alphanumeric text that has at minimum 4 instances of each step but possibly a 5th followed by all my data. I want to output only the last iteration of each step to a text file and delete all the others how would I do this?

Example: each iteration should be on its own line

Input file: data.dat

```
1 step1.1 
1 step1.2 
1 step1.3 
1 step1.4 
2 step2.1 
2 step2.2  
2 step2.3 
2 step2.4 
2 step2.5
```

Desired output:

```
1 step1.4
2 step2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. this may destroy the order: just remember the most recent line for each key:

   ```
   awk '{line[$1] = $0} END {for (key in line) print line[key]}' data.dat
   ```
2. reverse the file and print the *first* time you see a key, then re-reverse the output (this is a "famous" awk idiom)

   ```
   tac data.dat | awk '!seen[$1]++' | tac
   ```

Comment: The second option worked perfectly, Thanks for your help!